# Excel date difference #Value error

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two columns:
C2=4/27/15 11:00:26 AM
D2=4/27/15 11:01:46 AM

I'm trying to calculate the time difference in seconds using the formula 
=(D2-C2)*24*60*60

But I'm getting #Value error.

Answer (score 4):

Generally a #VALUE error means you are trying to do math on a text value. One of your dates is probably in text format.

Try retyping your dates and see if that makes your formula work.

If you need to have the actual seconds in a number you can use elsewhere then your formula should work, if the dates are in the correct format.

Comment: I did some testing and put a space in front of one of my date values and I generated a #VALUE error.  So along these lines - there could be something wrong with the format of one of your dates - make sure there are no extra characters (i.e. spaces) and that your date is typed in perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the specific ways to get the time difference between two dates in two different cells - notice the cell format is important:

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

And the DATEDIF function gives you the difference in days/months/years
    =DATEDIF(C2,D2,"M")

Answer (score 0):

You should use the INT function

```
=INT((D2-C2)*86400)
```

And as @Tember mentioned, cell formats are important..